# Adding an item to an object in a list with foreach

Tags: c#, .net, list, asp.net-core, foreach

I'm designing a web api and I'm trying to add the fields you can see in the following class inside an object named Data.

```
public partial class DataResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("data")]
    public List<Kullanicilar> Data { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```
public partial class Kullanicilar
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int KullaniciId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("ad_soyad")]
    public string AdSoyad { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("il")]
    public string Il { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("ilce")]
    public string Ilce { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("eposta")]
    public string Eposta { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("telefon")]
    public string Telefon { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("kart")]
    public string Kart { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("rfid")]
    public string Rfid { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("durum")]
    public byte Durum { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't know how to add every data from database to these list elements. I want to add items to the users list under the data object. I want every record to be saved in this list with a foreach logic.

My Controller Code:

```
public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var data = db.Kullanicilars.ToList();

            var result = new DataResponse()
            {
            Data = new List<Kullanicilar>()
                {
            new Kullanicilar()
            {
            KullaniciId = 1,
            AdSoyad = "",
            Il = "",
            Ilce = "",
            Eposta = "",
            Telefon = "",
            Kart = "",
            Rfid = "",
            Durum = 1
        },

    }
            };
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

.net core list problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run a loop and add each item to the list like this.

```
var result = new DataResponse();
result.Data = new List<Kullanicilar>();
foreach (var item data)
{
    result.Data.Add(new Kullanicilar()
    {
        KullaniciId = item.KullaniciId,
        AdSoyad = item.AdSoyad,
        Il = item.Il,
        Ilce = item.Ilce,
        Eposta = item.Eposta,
        Telefon = item.Telefon,
        Kart = item.Kart,
        Rfid = item.Rfid,
        Durum = item.Durum
    });
}
return Json(result);
```

Comment: tnx so much bro my problem it solved it :) <3